# Which tecnologies I should use to deploy UDP listener on IIS7? (with .NET)

Tags: .net, iis-7, udp, asp.net-mvc-3

There is the IIS7 with ASP.NET MVC site.
I want to add an udp listener to IIS.

Is it advisable to this?
Which tecnologies I should use?

May be, just create Windosw Service with UDP listener?

Answer (score 0):

You will never have IIS respond to UDP call.

I would go for building a custom UDP WCF Binding and host it with WAS.

Some articles can be found around the internet i.e. http://dotmad.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-udp-multicast-channel-in-wcf.html